# How do I exclude some subsections in section, while other subsections within the same chapter not?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocstyle

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, headsepline]{scrbook} 

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Chapter one}
 \section{Section one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.two}
 \section{Section one.two}
 \subsection{Subsection one.two.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.two.two}
 \section{Section one.three}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.two}

\end{document}
```

But I want the following toc:

> 1 Chapter one 
>   1.1 Section one.one 
>   1.1.1 Subsection one.one.one 
>   1.1.2 Subsection one.one.two 
>   1.2 Section one.two <<<--- here subsections are missing 
>   1.3 Section one.three 
>   1.3.1 Subsection one.one.one 
>   1.3.2 Subsection one.one.two

Excluding some subsections via
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
didn't work or maybe I implemented it wrong. Any hints?

Comment: So you only want to exclude stuff from the toc?

Comment: Correct, however, the answer below did work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to protect the \setcounter:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, headsepline]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Chapter one}
 \section{Section one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.two}
 \section{Section one.two}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
 \subsection{Subsection one.two.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.two.two}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
 \section{Section one.three}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.one}
 \subsection{Subsection one.one.two}

\end{document}

 You can also use the tocvsec2 package https://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2
```